# Show $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{c_k}{(n-k)!}=1$ where $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n=\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}$

Tags: calculus

Show $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{c_k}{(n-k)!}=1$$ for each $n\geq 0$, where $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n=\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}.$$

Since $$e^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}$$ and $$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$$ on $[-1,1)$, so we have, by multiplying directly, $$e^{-x}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x}=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\right)x^n$$ hence $$c_k=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}.$$
Now plugging it into the formula gives us $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{c_k}{(n-k)!}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{(n-k)!}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!},$$
but I got no useful result playing with induction, index manipulation, and spreading out all the terms, etc.

So I set $f(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}$ so that $$c_k = \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$$ and $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{c_k}{(n-k)!}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!(n-k)!}=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{n!}$$ which seems promising, because binomials usually take us to something like $(1+x)^n$ and this easily goes to $1$ if we set $x=0$ or something.

But we doesn't have power terms here, so I got stuck. I feel this is the right way to approach, not sure. Any idea or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n=\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}$$ that
$$e^x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n=\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n.$$ 
Now it is possible to compare the coefficients of $x^n$ on both sides of the equation.

Comment: This is just beautiful. How did you figure it out?

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{c_k}{(n-k)!}$ looks like the coefficient of $x^n$ of the product of $e^x$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n$.